# *Can anyone guide me where I am doing wrong.*

Tags: case

*Count: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: [] Trigger.Count: line 63, column 1*
**ABC Firm needs to make the service desk more productive. They have an idea to create Case Solutions as a reference guide for customers and service agents if any case resolution is accepted by the customer.
Requirement Details

- Create a custom object ‘Case Solution’ with fields Case Description, Resolution.
- Create a custom field ‘Accept Solution’ as a checkbox on the Case object.
- Create a custom field ‘Resolution’ as a text area on Case Object.
- Whenever a case has the status ‘Closed’ and its ‘Accept Solution’ checkbox is selected; a new Case Solution record should be created.**

**Trigger Code**

```
trigger NewCaseSolutions on Case (after insert,after update)
{

    //Declaration Section
    List <Case_Solution__c> toinsertlist = new List <Case_Solution__c>();
    Set<Id> caseID = new Set<Id> ();
    
    //Get Id of case records
    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) {
        for (Case case1 : trigger.New) {
            caseID.add(case1.ID);
        }    
    }
    
    //fetch case details
    List<case> caseList = new List<case> ();
    caseList =[Select Id,Resolution__c,Description,Accept_Solution__c,Status from case where Id in :caseID];
    
    //create case solution record
    for(Case cs : caseList) {
        if(cs.Status == 'Closed' && cs.Accept_Solution__c == true && cs.Description != null && cs.Resolution__c != null) {
            Case_Solution__c temp = new Case_Solution__c();
            temp.Name = 'Test';
            temp.Case_Description__c = cs.Description;
            temp.Resolution__c = cs.Resolution__c;
          //  temp.Case__c = cs.Id;
            toinsertlist.add(temp);
        }
    }
    //Insert case solution record
    insert toinsertlist; 
}
```

**Test**

```
@isTest
public class TestNewCaseSolution {
//Test Class setup
    @istest static void testSolution()
    {
        //create List for object Case
       List<Case> CL = new List<Case>();
        
       
                Case cs1 = new Case();
                 cs1.Name__c='Maggi';
                 cs1.Status='closed';
                 cs1.Accept_Solution__c=true;
        //add record in to the list
        CL.add(cs1);
                 Case cs2=new Case();
                  cs2.Name__c='test case';   
                  cs2.Status='Working';
                  cs2.Accept_Solution__c=false;
        //add record in to the list
        CL.add(cs2);
        
        //insert record
                 insert CL;
        //update record
                 update CL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a trigger related to the case solution object? I think the error could be in this trigger and not the case one.

Comment: I paste the trigger code also.